# How to cast HLS/m3u8 stream to the default chromecast receiver?

Tags: chromecast

We could not cast a m3u8 stream video by our sender to the default chromecast receiver. Where is the problem?

1. Does the default chromecast receiver support HLS streaming?
2. To realize it,do we need change any parameters when casting media in sender?
3. What does the CORS means? How to configure this? Please tell us the details.

Answer (score -6):

You filed an issue on the Cast SDK issue tracker with the same exact question so I will give you the same answer as I gave you there: all of these have been explained in our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) and a number of samples available [here](https://github.com/googlecast) that do the same thing so do your exercise and then come back here with real concrete questions if you have any.

Comment: I have combed over your Google Cast Sender API numerous times and I have not been able to find anything on HLS streams in a sender application. Nor do the samples you referenced do anything with HLS.

Comment: CastVideos-android app has HLS samples, so you did not search well. That app has samples for HLS, DASH and mp4.

Comment: @c.dunlap  BTW, next time try to ask first before marking an answer as not useful.